# How to add json data to table or jqueygrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, oauth-2.0

I am using oauth2.0 for accessing `Onhub` site for uploading and downloading files and creating folders.

When I am getting the details of the files I am getting in this format

```
{"total_entries":2,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1,"per_page":2,"items":[{"workspace":{"background_color":"white","data_room":false,"default_sort":"alphabetical","default_view":"list","id":330201,"name":"MyWorkSpace","updated_at":"2013-05-02T05:55:02-07:00","root_folder_id":166325721,"owner_id":991101,"is_owner":true,"effective_role":"Administrator","audit_trail":true,"require_agreement":false,"agreement_accepted":false}},{"workspace":{"background_color":"white","data_room":true,"default_sort":"alphabetical","default_view":"list","id":335496,"name":"Test","updated_at":"2013-05-02T06:02:17-07:00","root_folder_id":172136546,"owner_id":991101,"is_owner":true,"effective_role":"Administrator","audit_trail":true,"require_agreement":false,"agreement_accepted":false}}]}
```

I want to bind the `oauth 2.0` output to jquery grid or table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the code where you setup your jqGrid?